# Freeradius authentification against active directory using MS_CHAP

Tags: freeradius, ntlm-authentication

I'm trying to create an authentification using Freeradius 3 with the MS_CHAP authentification protocol. I set up my active directory. It works:

```
$ ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --username=admin --password=Qwerty01 --domain=DOMAIN.LOCAL
NT_STATUS_OK: The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

However, I can't authenticate using radtest:

```
$ radtest -t mschap admin Qwerty01 localhost 0 testing123
Sent Access-Request Id 232 from 0.0.0.0:51847 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 131
    User-Name = "admin"
    MS-CHAP-Password = "Qwerty01"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.0.1
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "Qwerty01"
    MS-CHAP-Challenge = 0x044d30abb8866f26
    MS-CHAP-Response = 0x0001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000803c721e5b12ff86836a1873e1c0f62d18e2c054b83c940f
Received Access-Reject Id 232 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:51847 length 61
    MS-CHAP-Error = "\000E=691 R=1 C=f25227a7f4150df5 V=2"
(0) -: Expected Access-Accept got Access-Reject
```

Here is my freeradius logs:

```
...
(1)   authenticate {
(1) mschap: Client is using MS-CHAPv1 with NT-Password
(1) mschap: Executing: /bin/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --allow-mschapv2 --username=%{mschap:User-Name:-None} --domain=%{%{mschap:NT-Domain}:-DOMAIN.LOCAL} --challenge=%{mschap:Challenge:-00} --nt-response=%{mschap:NT-Response:-00}:
(1) mschap: EXPAND --username=%{mschap:User-Name:-None}
(1) mschap:    --> --username=admin
(1) mschap: ERROR: No NT-Domain was found in the User-Name
(1) mschap: EXPAND --domain=%{%{mschap:NT-Domain}:-DOMAIN.LOCAL}
(1) mschap:    --> --domain=DOMAIN.LOCAL
(1) mschap: mschap1: 04
(1) mschap: EXPAND --challenge=%{mschap:Challenge:-00}
(1) mschap:    --> --challenge=044d30abb8866f26
(1) mschap: EXPAND --nt-response=%{mschap:NT-Response:-00}
(1) mschap:    --> --nt-response=803c721e5b12ff86836a1873e1c0f62d18e2c054b83c940f
(1) mschap: ERROR: Program returned code (1) and output 'Reading winbind reply failed! (0xc0000001)'
(1) mschap: ERROR: Reading winbind reply failed! (0xc0000001)
(1) mschap: Authentication failed
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so, you will need to grant permission to the /var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged folder for your radius user. Example:

```
setfacl -m u:radiusd:rx winbindd_privileged
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `/var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged` is owned by a specific group (which happens to be `winbindd_priv` in Ubuntu 22.04).
Then you can achieve the same goal by adding user `radiusd` (`freerad` in Ubuntu 22.04) to this group:

```
usermod -a -G winbindd_priv radiusd
```